# Reference for Sobolev space definition on the boundary

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I am looking for a reference for the definition of Sobolev spaces $H^s$ for the boundary of a open bounded set $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. Here s is a positive real number. Preferably I would like to see this for fourier transforms, but any other will do as well.

Please ask me for further details if you should need any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I found a source for these. I will post it here for future use for anybody looking for the same thing. The book where I found these was *William McLean, Strongly elliptic systems and boundary integral equations* and from that book, chapter three.